# Преобразовать в массив json

Tags: php, json

Помогите преобразовать строку в массив json [такой запрос](http://tajmarket.ru/tetes/files/)

такого кода:

```
<?
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    //if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $keyword = $_POST['id'];
        $data = array(
              'iframe_delete'=>'true',
              'varname'=> 'intelSearchData',
              '__number'=> '2',
              'keyword'=> 'камера'//$keyword,
              );

        $ch = curl_init('http://connectkeyword.aliexpress.com/lenoIframeJson.htm?'.http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'IE20');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookies.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $page=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $json = substr($page, 45, -9);
        //$json = json_decode($json);
        print_r($json);
    //}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну можете попробовать `json_decode`:

```
$obj = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

Ну и `$obj`- многомерный массив.

А если хотите средствами js это делать, то используйте `JSON.parse(string)` предварительно забрав Вашу строку в var string.

Comment: так уже сделал не помогает показывает пустоту.

Comment: Так у Вас, по той ссылке, массив корявый. Данные ячейки должны быть в двойных кавычках, как имена, так и значения, а не в одинарных, как у Вас. Иначе decode-р не сможет нормально обойти строку. Касательно чисел, у Вас несколько count-ов используют такой вид "8,059". Если это число целое, избавьтесь от разделения на тысячи, число не должно содержать запятых, или же, должно быть в кавычках.

Comment: а если парсить через `JSON.parse(string)` так легче думаю?

Comment: Это не меняет сути дела. У Вас массив который идет на парсер невалидный

Comment: Информация идет не с моего сервера, как можно поменять одинарный кавычки на двойных?

Comment: `$jsondata = str_replace("'", '"', $jsondata);` тоже самое сделайте со всеми Вашими id в массиве: `$jsondata = str_replace('id','"id"', $jsondata);`

Comment: спасибо кавычки поменялось но вопрос остается все равно не преобразуется в массив json